# Validate Firestore write results on Firebase Cloud Functions unit tests

Tags: typescript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a good way to validate Firestore write results on a Cloud Function reliably? The official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) recommends mocking every Firestore call, but there are a few caveats. The most critical one is that there are several ways to achieve similar results. For example, these 3 calls produce the same result:

```
await admin.firestore().collection('payments').add(myPayment);

await admin.firestore().collection('payments').doc().set(myPayment);

const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
batch.create(admin.firestore().collection('payments').doc(), myPayment);
await batch.commit();
```

I can think of at least a couple more that would produce the exact same result. So it's very hard to mock all calls, and even if I do the test becomes too dependent on the implementation. For example, if the code doesn't use batched writes and the developer refactors the code to use them, the test would need to be rewritten, even though the final result doesn't change. Or even if they replace an add with a doc().set, like the first two examples. And creating tests that considers all possible implementations would be complex, brittle and very verbose.

One option would be to use the emulator, or even a test Firebase project, but that would cause an extra layer of complexity, lower execution performance and introduce external dependencies, so that would actually be an integration test.

Is there a better solution that I'm not seeing?